# using DBI causes module file compilation Error

Tags: perl, perl-module, dbi

- perl version is 5.8.8
- mysql version is 5.5.42
- DBI version is 1.633 and DBD::mysql version is 4.022

I am on shared hosting server.
i have a perl module file  which works fine. i can use its subs with no problem from a perl script file. if i add this to pm file,

```
use DBI;
my $username = "username";
my $password = "password";
my $dsn = "DBD:mysql:database"; # i changed DBD to DBI as well but no good
```

still everything works fine.
but as soon I add the following line to perl module file, the perl script file starts complaining "***Compilation failed in require"***

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $username, $password ) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

I tried googling it but no result. Any idea?

Comment: Please fix your data source name: it should start with `DBI:`. It looks like there's something wrong with the installation of your `DBD::mysql` driver module. Try adding `use DBD::mysql` beneath `use DBI` and see what error that gives you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to create a dbi handle which could be used by the subs of that module but i was getting error before i could use that(as i mentioned in the question).
May be it is a security feature of modules, Apprently i can only use dbi in the sub form,

> use DBI;
>   sub databaseHandle{
>   my $username = "username";
>   my $password = "password";
>   my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database";
>   my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $username, $password ) or die $DBI::errstr;
>   return $dbh   }
>   my $dbh = databaseHandle();

i dont know the particular reason but this is how i am using it.
Thanks for all the help and idea.

Answer (score -2):

The data source must be "`DBI:mysql:database=my_database`", where you pass the kind and the name of your database.

The error occurs because the database driver module `DBD::mysql` must be installed. Inquire with your hoster whether that module is installed or whether you can install it yourself.

Comment: A missing driver module would result in the usual `Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC`. The OP is getting `Compilation failed in require`, which means the file is there but contains an error

Comment: I had mentioned in my question that i have dbd::mysql version 4.022, so it is there.